# typeerror '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, intervals

I am sorting data within a dataframe, I am using the data from one column, binning it to intervals of 2 units and then I want a list of each of the intervals created. This is the code:

```
df = gpd.read_file(file)
final = df[df['i_h100']>=0] 
final['H_bins']=pd.cut(x=final['i_h100'], bins=np.arange(0, 120+2, 2))
HBins = list(np.unique(final['H_bins']))
```

With most of my dataframes this works totally fine but occasionally I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/folders/bg/5n2pqdj53xv1lm099dt8z2lw0000gn/T/ipykernel_2222/1548505304.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
HBins = list(np.unique(final['H_bins']))

File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in unique

File "/Users/heatherkay/miniconda3/envs/gpd/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 272, in unique
ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)

File "/Users/heatherkay/miniconda3/envs/gpd/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 333, in _unique1d
ar.sort()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

I don't understand why, or how to resolve this.

Comment: you may have **nan**. Did you check ?

Comment: Yeah I checked the dataframe

Comment: I'll try adding in a command to remove nan, maybe there's something hidden that my eyes can't see!

Comment: Nope, it's definitely not that

Comment: okey, can you provide the sample of data ?

Comment: You can access one of the dataframes here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yzwMl2y-hBvbl6wBiQQgv6M7gdzHqsbP?usp=share_link